# Spark 2.0 DataSourceRegister configuration error while saving DataFrame as cvs

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, dataframe, orc

I'm trying to save a data frame to cvs in in Spark 2.0, Scala 2.11 (process of migrating code from Spark 1.6).

```
sparkSession.sql("SELECT * FROM myTable").
      coalesce(1).
      write.
      format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
      option("header","true").
      save(config.resultLayer)
```

Is the spark session built correctly?

```
implicit val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
  .master("local")
  .appName("com.yo.go")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
```

The error is received only at runtime (code compiles).

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc.DefaultSource could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:224)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:377)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:427)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:194)
    at com.apple.geo.contigu.common.JoinFeatures$.savePairSummaries(JoinFeatures.scala:343)
    at com.apple.geo.contigu.Main$.main(Main.scala:32)
    at com.apple.geo.contigu.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/spark/sql/hive/orc/DefaultSource.createRelation(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext;[Ljava/lang/String;Lscala/Option;Lscala/Option;Lscala/collection/immutable/Map;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/sources/HadoopFsRelation; @35: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/spark/sql/hive/orc/OrcRelation' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/spark/sql/sources/HadoopFsRelation' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @35
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/apache/spark/sql/hive/orc/DefaultSource', 'org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext', '[Ljava/lang/String;', 'scala/Option', 'scala/Option', 'scala/collection/immutable/Map' }
    stack: { 'org/apache/spark/sql/hive/orc/OrcRelation' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: b200 1c2b c100 1ebb 000e 592a b700 22b6
    0000010: 0026 bb00 2859 2c2d b200 2d19 0419 052b
    0000020: b700 30b0                              

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2595)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2895)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:354)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:373)
    ... 27 more
```

Is there something obvious that I've overlooked? Need more details? Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have Hive configurated correctly in your cluster?

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim I am running locally. I double checked that hadoop and hive exist but I'm not sure how to check that hive is configured correctly. Do you have any pointers on what I should be looking for? Just to be clear, if I do a df.take(5).foreach(println) my hive query executes as expected. It's only when I attempt to save to disk that I encounter this error (query execution never begins).

Answer (score 0):

ran into roughly same situation.

if you just want to do a quick run using local computer instead of fully configured cluster.

- turn off `enable hive`
- in pom.xml make sure relevant dependencies are `<scope>provided</scope>`